# Wordpress: Get Terms of current archive or custom post type

Tags: wordpress, filter, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I'm trying to code a little Taxonomy-Filter for my Custom-Post-Type-Pages, Archives and Term-Pages. Therefore I try to find out, which taxonomy is used on current page.

For example: http://www.domain.de/taxonomy, or archive of custom-post-type like http://www.domain.de/portfolio

Example: I build a portfolio-page with custom post-type. I gave this the taxonomies "skills" and "category". On the page-portfolio.php and archive-portfolio.php there will be a filter with the terms of "skills" and "category".

`$terms = get_the_terms($post->id, 'TAXONOMY_NAME');` should not fit, because, the filter should fit for many unknown Taxonomy and Custom-post-types. Also there is no fixed taxonomy-name available.

```
        $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
        $incname = $term->taxonomy;
        $args = array( 'hide_empty=0' );
        $terms = get_terms( $incname, $args );

        if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            //do spomething
            else {
            //do spomething
            }
        }
```

The code above works only, if the current page is already a term-page (http://www.domain.de/taxonomy/term)

```
        $term = $wp_query->queried_object;
        $taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);

        if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            //do spomething
            else {
            //do spomething
            }
        }
```

The code above works only, if the current page is already a term-page (http://www.domain.de/taxonomy/term)

How can I get the taxonomies and (child-)terms of current post-type?

Comment: Did you find a solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `wp_get_post_terms()`?(http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)

From your description, it looks like it should give you the terms you need.

HTH!

=C=

Comment: `<?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args ); ?>`  I transferred this code to something like this:

   `$tax = $wp_query->queried_object;
   $group = wp_get_post_terms($tax);
   print_r($group);`

This prints array, but with wrong terms... I got terms from other taxonomy... not current O.o